# Websocket with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

So basically I want to create websocket from api that need using websocket to create some alert, so far I have try using `ClientWebsocket` and it work as I expected but sometimes not, something like this

```
public static async Task<ListenerContent> ConnectCall(string uri, string valcookie, string xapp, string listenerName, string terminalId, string userCrm)
    {
        ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;
        var objListener = new ListenerContent();
        try
        {
            webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
            webSocket.Options.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", valcookie);
            await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
            var terminalListener = CreateListener(xapp, listenerName);
            RetrieveCurrentCalls(xapp, listenerName, terminalId);
            objListener = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListenerContent>(terminalListener);
            await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket, terminalId, userCrm), Send(webSocket));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in receive - {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (webSocket != null)
                webSocket.Dispose();

            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
        return objListener;
    }
```

so I want to ask about is there any other way to connect this socket with javascript or other library, because I use this with console application and not really smooth

Comment: Just wondering, have you checked out PubNub to send and receive your messages instead of websockets.

Comment: Or http://rltmjs.com/ that allows you to switch between Socket.io and PubNub.

Comment: actually I use websocket because API that I have to consume using websocket, so I don't have any control on that, basically I want to triger response from websocket that already connected for notification purpose..is there any some enlightment about this @JordanSchuetz

Comment: @CraigConover hmm, any other idea? because if I have to learn that it takes more time

Comment: It's a simple API that wraps both protocols. It could not be easier

Comment: can you provide some example in my case? @CraigConover I really appreciate if you can provide some example